# Rails catch all route prevents access to public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

... which makes sense. I'm using the catch all route for page routing in a custom CMS. However I would still like to access user uploaded assets in my public folder. My route is as follows:

```
match "(*url)" => 'pages#show'
```

And my controller does this:

```
def show
    @page = Page.where(:url => ['/', params[:url]].join).first
     begin
        render :template => "templates/" + @page.template.slug
     rescue
        render "public/404.html"
     end
end
```

Now I know I could probably parse the url in my controller but I was wondering if there is a better rails way - for example, can I add an exception to the catch all route?

Thoughts?

Comment: Static files should take precedence over Rails.

Comment: But they don't seem to.. I'm still hitting the controller when trying to access /public/images/dinner.jpeg for example

Comment: @tadman Oh my bad, I shouldn't have included public in the url. Accessing /images/dinner.jpeg works fine. If you write your response as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally static files will take precedence over Rails generated content if your server is configured correctly.

Be careful not to confuse the path relative to the application, such as `/public/images/test.png` with the path relative to the web root, which would be `/images/test.png`. This conflicting definition of "path" has confused many developers.

Answer (score 2):

On Rails 5, the default production configuration enables the public file server by an environment variable flag.  Either set the `enabled` value directly to `true` or make sure the `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` environment variable is set. The files in the public directory will then be served and the catch all route won't catch them instead.

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```